# How to loop through columns a given number of times

Tags: excel, vba

I have my top row filled with values. I would like to insert two columns between each of these values, until the last non-empty cell in my top row.

I'm stuck there in my code:

```vb
Sub AddCol()
'
' AddCol Macro
'

For i = 1 To 2

    Sheets("CashFlow").Select
    Columns(i + 1).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=x1ToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will Work For you:

```
Sub AddCol() ' ' AddCol Macro '

With Thisworkbook.Worksheets("CashFlow")

For i = 1 To .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column * 3 Step 3


    .Columns(i + 1).Insert Shift:=x1ToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .Columns(i + 1).Insert Shift:=x1ToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Next i

End With    

End Sub
```

Comment: Avoid the `Sheets("CashFlow").Activate` use `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CashFlow")` instead

Answer (score 2):

A couple things.

a) You need to get a value for the number of columns so you can loop through and add

b) When looping, loop from highest to lowest because you are adding columns if you loop lowest to highest it will effect you counters and you will end up not looping through the entire header set.

See below code:

```vb
Sub ColumnsAdd()

    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myWS As Worksheet

    Set myWS = Sheets("CashFlow")

    lCol = myWS.Cells(1, myWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = lCol To 1 Step -1
        myWS.Columns(i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        myWS.Columns(i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You should fully reference the `Columns(i)` because if the procedure switches sheets the insert will go to the activesheet.

Comment: Thanks @Damian made an assumption, but have edited.

Comment: Hello Dean, had a second look at the code - what the role of the J variable?

Comment: @khalilsalame good spot. I originally had the `j` variable because I was going to loop through to add the columns. However, I chose to just have two `Columns.Insert` on separate lines. I have updated the code to show this.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way:

```
.Columns(i + 1).Resize(, 2).Insert Shift:=x1ToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```